# how to get Test Case name with rally API

Tags: python, html, rally, mako, pyral

I am trying to write a loop that will return a table with Test Sets and Test cases. However, i am not able to get the name of the test case, but rally returns an "Object ID (OID). The code is given as

```
_M_writer(u'</p>\r\n<table  class="objects" style="width: 60%">\r\n\t\t<tr>\r\n\t\t\t<th>TestSets</td>\r\n\t\t\t<th>TestCases</th>\r\n\t\t</tr>\r\n')

        for ts in testSets:

                __M_writer(u'\t\t\t\t')
                tc = ts.TestCases


                if tc:

                    __M_writer(u'<tr>')
                    __M_writer(u'<td>')
                    __M_writer(unicode(ts.FormattedID))
                    __M_writer(u'\t\t\t\t</td>')

                    __M_writer(u'<td>')

                    __M_writer(filters.html_escape(unicode(tc.FormattedID)))
                    __M_writer(u'</td>')

                __M_writer(u'</tr>\r\n')
                pass

        __M_writer(u'</table>\n')
```

tc.FormattedID gives me an attribute error. See below

```
 print >> fh, template.render(**workContext)

  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\mako\template.py", line 397, in render
    return runtime._render(self, self.callable_, args, data)

  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\mako\runtime.py", line 764, in _render
    **_kwargs_for_callable(callable_, data))

  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\mako\runtime.py", line 796, in _render_context
    _exec_template(inherit, lclcontext, args=args, kwargs=kwargs)

  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\mako\runtime.py", line 822, in _exec_template
    callable_(context, *args, **kwargs)

  File "C:\Users\xxx\Documents\xx\tools\xxx\tmp\audit.base.html.py", line 130,               in render_body

    context['self'].content(**pageargs)
  File "C:\Users\xxx\Documents\TOOLS_WS\tools\xxxx\tmp\Validation Test Plan.html.py",               line 171, in render_content
    __M_writer(filters.html_escape(unicode(tc.FormattedID)))
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'FormattedID'
```

Please need help. Thanks

Comment: Could you please review the code formatting?

Answer (score 2):

it just so happens that I was missing a 'for`loop in my code:`ts.TestCases` is returning a list of Test Cases and not a single Test Case.

The corrected code is the following:

```
__M_writer(u'</p>\r\n<table  class="objects" style="width: 60%">\r\n\t\t<tr>\r\n\t\t\t<th>TestSets</td>\r\n\t\t\t<th>TestCases</th>\r\n\t\t</tr>\r\n')

    for ts in testSets:

            __M_writer(u'\t\t\t\t')
            testCaseObjectList = ts.TestCases
            for tc in testCaseObjectList:
                if tc:
                     __M_writer(u'<tr>')
                     __M_writer(u'<td>')
                     __M_writer(unicode(ts.FormattedID))
                     __M_writer(u'\t\t\t\t</td>')
                     __M_writer(u'<td>')
                     __M_writer(filters.html_escape(unicode(tc.FormattedID)))
                     __M_writer(u'</td>')
                     __M_writer(u'</tr>\r\n')
                pass

     __M_writer(u'</table>\n')
```

Cheers.

Comment: Note that an error might be raised if the Test Set has no Test Cases

Answer (score 0):

This is not specific to Python, but Name has to be fetched explicitly to get to it. Try to use `tc._refObjectName`. There is no need to fetch `_refObjectName` and it is the same as Name.

Comment: I stil got this error:__M_writer(filters.html_escape(unicode(tc._refObjectName)))
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute '_refObjectName'